# Nock - Bodies don't match

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest, nock

Why does Nock give me an error saying that bodies don't match??

here is my code.

```
it('Should Delete /user/removeuserskills', function(done){

    mockRequest
    .delete('/user/removeuserskills',{skill:'accountant'})
    .reply(201,{
      'status':200,
      'message': '200: Successfully deleted skill'
      })
    .log(console.log)
    request
    .delete('/user/removeuserskills',{skill:'accountant'})
    .end(function(err, res){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
      expect(res.body.status).to.equal(200);
      expect(res.body.message).to.equal('200: Successfully deleted skill');}
      done();
    });

  });
```

I get this response when I use the `.log`

I have no clue why it tells me bodies dont match. I get this specifically.

```
matching http://localhost:8080 to DELETE http://localhost:8080/user/removeuserskills: true 
bodies don't match:                                                                        
 { skill: 'accountant' }                                                                   

{ Error: Nock: No match for request {                                                      
  "method": "DELETE",                                                                      
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/user/removeuserskills"                                     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/189) at github that you currently are not able to use .delete(url, data).

But you can fix it easily like this:

```js
mockRequest
 .delete('/user/removeuserskills', {skill: 'accountant'})
 .reply(201, {
  'status': 200,
  'message': '200: Successfully deleted skill'
 })
 .log(console.log)

request
 .delete('/user/removeuserskills')
 //Just call .send here instead
 .send({skill: 'accountant'})
 .end(function (err, res) {
  ...
  done();
 });
```

If you call .send(data) instead of passing data into .delete method it works just fine.

Comment: omg life saver, I was going to do exactly that, this morning. :D haha thanks